# What's the design on their aprons?

Tags: denkigai-no-honya-san

On the aprons (at least I think they're aprons) of the people that work on the Horse's Bone, a weird design can be seen:

[image: After the midnight release rush]

Is this supposed to be a (weird) horse or something like that, which alludes to the shop's name?
Or is it something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a horse's head eating a carrot, with crossbone in the background.

[image: Uma no Hone]

"Uma no Hone" (Horse's Bone) is a parody of the popular real-life chain of doujin shops under the "Tora no Ana" ("Tiger's Den") name. ("Mikan Books" is a parody of "Melon Books")